# Clearing Message Input in a Socket React App when using Rooms

Tags: javascript, reactjs, socket.io

I'm working on a react app and after following a tutorial on rooms I can not longer get the input to clear when the message is inputed. The commented out sections are things I've tried. I think what I want to do us somehow refer to messageRef in the socket.js file and set it to an empty string. Alternatively I think I might want to move the room functions to Chat.js but the way I learned to set it up was in a seperate file.

For Clientside I have this Chat.js component and the socket.js in the utils folder

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react";
import {initiateSocket, disconnectSocket, subscribeToChat, handleTyping, sendMessage } from "../../utils/socket/socket";
import "./listStyle.css";
var user = "User";
var store = "Store"
var storeMessage = user + " is going to " + store;


function Chat() {
    const rooms = ['1', '2'];
    let messageRef = useRef();
    const [room, setRoom] = useState(rooms[0]);
    const [typing, setTyping] = useState("")
    const [message, setMessage] = useState("");
    const [chat, setChat] = useState([]);
    //keeps inputing for every letter
    // const clearInput = (input) =>
    // {
    //     //input = "";
    //     console.log("input cleared")
    // }
    // const handleSendMessage = () => {
    //     sendMessage(room, user + ": " + messageRef.current.value)
    //     messageRef.current.value = "";
    // }
    //const handleTyping = () => { socket.emit("typing", user + ": is typing") }
    useEffect(() => {
        if (room) initiateSocket(room);
        subscribeToChat((err, data) => {
            if (err) return;
            setChat(oldChats => [...oldChats, data])
            setTyping("")
        });
        return () => {
            disconnectSocket();
        }
    }, [room]);
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Group: {room}</h1>
            { rooms.map((r, i) =>
                <button onClick={() => setRoom(r)} key={i}>{r}</button>)}
            <h1>{storeMessage}</h1>
            <div id="list-chat">
                <div id="chat-window">
                    <div id="output" >
                        {chat.map((m, i) => <p key={i}>{m}</p>)}
                    </div>
                    <div id="feedback" >{typing}</div>
                </div>
                <input id="message" autoComplete="off" type="text" 
                defaultValue = ""
                 placeholder="message"
                //value={message}
                    onChange={() => setMessage(messageRef.current.value)} ref={messageRef}
                    //onChange={() => handleTyping(room, user + ": is typing.")}
                    />
                <button id="send" 
                onClick={() => sendMessage(room, user + ": " + messageRef.current.value)} 
                //onClick={() => console.log("test")}
                //onClick={() => sendMessage(room, user + ": " + messageRef.current.value)} 
                //onchange={e => messageRef.current.value = ""}
                //onClick={handleSendMessage()}
                //onChange={() => handleTyping(room, user + ": is typing." )}
                //only clears current room
                //have to comment out on startup
                //onChange={console.log("test")}
                //onSubmit={messageRef.current.value = ""}
                    >Send</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Chat;
```

socket.js
The message is sent using the sendMessage function

(these 3 are from before rooms were implemented

```
// import {io} from "socket.io-client";
// const socket = io.connect(process.env.PORT || "http://localhost:3001");
// export default socket;

import io from 'socket.io-client';
let socket;
export const initiateSocket = (room) => {
  socket = io('http://localhost:3000');
  console.log(`Connecting socket...`);
  if (socket && room) socket.emit('join', room);
}
export const disconnectSocket = () => {
  console.log('Disconnecting socket...');
  if(socket) socket.disconnect();
}
export const subscribeToChat = (cb) => {
  if (!socket) return(true);
  socket.on('chat', msg => {
    console.log('Websocket event received!');
    return cb(null, msg);
  });
}
export const handleSendMessage = () =>{
    
}
export const sendMessage = (room, message) => {
  if (socket) socket.emit('chat', {room, message });
  console.log("message sent")
  //message = "";
}
export const handleTyping = (room, message) =>{
    if (socket) socket.emit('typing', {room, message});
    //message = "";
    console.log("typing")
}
```

and my server side file (seperate from the actual server.js)

```
const socketio = require('socket.io');

//let rooms = ["room1", "room2"] 

const initializeSocketio = (server) => {
    const io = socketio(server, {
        cors: {
            origin: "http://localhost:3000",
            methods: ["GET", "POST"],
            allowedHeaders: ["my-custom-header"],
            credentials: true
        }
    });
    io.on('connection', function (socket) {
        console.log("made socket connection", socket.id)

        // socket.on('chat', function (data) {
        //     io.sockets.emit('chat', data)
        // });
        //doesn't do anything right now
        // socket.on('start-shop', function (data) {
        //     io.sockets.emit('start-shop', data)
        // });

        // socket.on('typing', function (data) {
        //     socket.broadcast.emit('typing', data)
        // });
        //room test
        // room1 = "room1";
        // socket.on('join1', function (room1) {
        //     //socket.join(room1);
        //     console.log(room1)
        // });
        // room2 = "room2";
        // socket.on('join2', function (room2) {
        //     //socket.join(room2);
        //     console.log(room2)
        // });
        //socket.in(room).emit('message', 'what is going on, party people?');
        // socket.in('foobar').emit('message', 'anyone in this room yet?');
        socket.on('disconnect', () =>
            console.log(`Disconnected: ${socket.id}`));
        socket.on('join', (room) => {
            console.log(`Socket ${socket.id} joining ${room}`);
            socket.join(room);
        });
        socket.on('chat', (data) => {
            const { message, room } = data;
            console.log(`msg: ${message}, room: ${room}`);
            io.to(room).emit('chat', message);
        });
        // socket.on('typing', (data) => {
        //     const { typing, room } = data;
        //     console.log(`msg: ${typing}, room: ${room}`);
        //     io.to(room).broadcast('typing', typing);
        // });
    });
}

module.exports = initializeSocketio;
```

Before I implemented rooms I was using List.js which did delete the input when the message was sent in the handleSentMessage function and it worked.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react";
import socket from "../../utils/socket/socket";
import "./listStyle.css";
var user = "User";
var store = "Store"
var storeMessage = user + " is going to " + store;
//room test
var room1 = "room1";
var room2 = "room2";

function List() {
    const messageRef = useRef();
    const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);
    const [typing, setTyping] = useState("")
    const [room, setRoom] = useState("");
    const handleSendMessage = () => {
        socket.emit("chat", user + ": " + messageRef.current.value)
        messageRef.current.value = ""
    }
    //room test
    //connect room 1
    const connectRoom1 = () => {
        console.log("button 1 clicked")
        // socket.on('join1', function (room1) {
        //     socket.emit('room1', room1)
        //     console.log("connected to room1")
        //     //need to do something with this
        //     setRoom()
        // });
        socket.emit('join1', "anything1")
    }
    //connect room 2
    const connectRoom2 = () => {
        // console.log("button 2 clicked")
        // socket.on('join2', function () {
        //     socket.emit('room2', room2)
        //     console.log("connected to room2")
        //     //need to do something with this
        //     setRoom()
        // });
        socket.emit('join2', "anything2")
    }
    //commented out for now
    // socket.on('connect', function(){
    //     socket.emit('room1', room1)
    // });
    // socket.on('connect', function(){
    //     socket.emit('room2', room2)
    // });
    //room test
    socket.on('message', function (data) {
        console.log('Incoming message:', data);
    });
    const handleTyping = () => { socket.emit("typing", user + ": is typing") }
    useEffect(() => {
        socket.on("chat", (data) => {
            setMessages((prevMessages) => ([...prevMessages, data]));
            setTyping("")
        });
        socket.on("typing", (data) => {
            setTyping(data)
            console.log(data)
        });
        return () => {
            socket.off("chat");
        }
        // dependency array, put user object in array if we want the callback function to fire everytime userobject sees a change
    }, [])
    return (
        <div>
            {/* connect to room 1 */}
            <button onClick={connectRoom1}> Room 1 </button>
            <br></br>
            {/* connect to room 2 */}
            <button onClick={connectRoom2}> Room 2 </button>
            <h1>{storeMessage}</h1>
            <div id="list-chat">
                <div id="chat-window">
                    <div id="output">
                        {messages.map((message, i) => (
                            <p key={i}>{message}</p>
                        ))}
                    </div>
                    <div id="feedback">{typing}</div>

                </div>
                <input id="message" autoComplete="off" type="text" placeholder="message" ref={messageRef} onChange={handleTyping} />
                <button id="send" onClick={handleSendMessage}>Send</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default List;
```

any ideas on what I need to do to get the input deleted when the message is sent.

I also want to try to reimplement the user: is typing message but that's a secondary priority.

Any hints or help to get pointed in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use a state to hold your input value, and you don't to use a ref for that, try something like:

```
const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("")
const handleSendMessage = (e) => {
        socket.emit("chat", user + ": " + e.target.value)
        setInputValue("")
       
    }

....

  <input id="message" autoComplete="off" type="text" placeholder="message" 
   ref={messageRef} onChange={handleTyping} value={inputValue}/>
```

To the typing feature, I would suggest a debounce, to avoid unnecessary events emitted. Take a look at https://github.com/xnimorz/use-debounce, for me one of the easiest debounce solution.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my first part.

```
const [myList, setList] = useState([]);
const messageRef = useRef(null);

------
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setList([...myList, messageRef.current.value]);
        // you can manually set the value of your input by the node ref
        messageRef.current.value = "";
        // Or you can reset your form element to its default values
        // e.currentTarget.reset();
      }
---
 <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
 </form>
```

I haven't tried the second part yet.